# What is the difference between "kid" and "kid around"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me what the difference is between *kid* and *kid around*? For example:

> Person A: I've accidentally ruined your painting.
>
> Person B: What?! I've been painting it for a week.
>
> Person A: Relax. I'm just **kidding**/**kidding around**.

Comment: What do you think the difference is? Why? Do you know exactly which each phrase means?

Comment: I'd say "I'm just pulling your leg” but then again, my idiolect is closer to British English than American.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"kid" refers to a specific instance where someone is making a joke, or playing a prank. On the other hand, "kid around" usually refers to multiple instances, perhaps even a regular pattern, of making jokes.

In the example you gave, "kidding" is probably more appropriate, since it appears to be a single instance of Person A playing a prank.

"kidding around" is sometimes used even for a single instance, and sounds quite natural to a native speaker. However, if you want to describe a regular pattern, then "kid" doesn't convey that accurately.